# PL/SQL Developer is flickering and shows an error

Tags: kubuntu, wine, kde

I want to migrate from Windows to Linux. I chose and installed Kubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. It is important for me to be able to use the Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer because the Oracle SQL Developer is useless garbage. I installed the WineHQ and then installed PL/SQL Developer using MSI installer. When I opened PL/SQL Developer is stated flickering and showed an error after some time. This is a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14y0RToSOeZtahyPCufR7jFXH0jSTGRgg) to the screencast of how PL/SQL Developer is flickering. It seems that it is a generic problem related to Wine and/or Linux, because Wine [says](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=935) that PL/SQL Developer worked with Wine on tests.

Laptop: [Lenovo ThinkPad T540p](https://www3.lenovo.com/za/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/T540p/p/22TP2TT540P)
Display resolution: 2880x1620
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4600 and NVIDIA GeForce GT 730M

Please help to solve issues with PL/SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

I can fix flickering issue by unchecking winecfg -> Graphics -> Allow the window manager to control the windows. But the second problem still exists. After opening the program, I do a little bit of action and get out an error.
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Below is a text from plsqldev.log file:

```
Version       : 7.5.1.0
Date          : Sat, 3 Feb 2018 22:54:17 +0400
OS            : Wine (64 bit)
RAD           : BDS 16.0
Dump          : $4C $8B $01 $C0 $E8 $04 $4D $85 $DB $0F $B6 $D0 $0F $B6 $C0 $4D $89 $44 $C2 $78 $74 $08 $49 $89 $8C $D3 $80 $00 $00 $00 $49 $83 
Section       : CreateThreadHook
Descr         : 

Address       : $000000007BC932AD - [000000007BC20000] ntdll.dll - ntdll -  -  (possible RtlVirtualUnwind+909) - 0[909]
Module        : ntdll.dll
Exception     : EAccessViolation
Message       : Access violation at address 000000007BC932AD in module 'ntdll.dll'. Invalid access of address 006F006D006D006F
Call Stack    : 00 $000000007BC932AD - [000000007BC20000] ntdll.dll - ntdll -  -  (possible RtlVirtualUnwind+909)
                01 $000000000067F0BB - [0000000000400000] plsqldev.exe - ECallStack - TEurekaBaseStackList - Build - 2154[155]
                02 $000000000091F988 - [0000000000400000] plsqldev.exe - ExceptionLog7 -  - GetCallStackDump - 468[184]
                03 $000000000092096D - [0000000000400000] plsqldev.exe - ExceptionLog7 -  - FullInternalErrorReport - 693[2829]
                04 $00000000005B9D15 - [0000000000400000] plsqldev.exe - EBase -  - InternalErrorSet - 1586[805]
                05 $000000000066E9AC - [0000000000400000] plsqldev.exe - EThreadsManager -  - CreateThreadHook - 1478[540]
                06 $00007FAEB8A9447F - [00007FAEB8A80000] winmm.dll - winmm -  -  (possible mmioRenameW+5567)


LastAddr      : $000000007BC932AD - [000000007BC20000] ntdll.dll - ntdll -  -  (possible RtlVirtualUnwind+909) - 0[909]
LastModule    : ntdll.dll
LastException : EAccessViolation
LastMessage   : Access violation at address 000000007BC932AD in module 'ntdll.dll'. Invalid access of address 006F006D006D006F.
Call Stack    : CallStack = nil

ActiveObj     : () 
ActiveAddr    : 

Bug report file is located here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\PLSQL Developer 12\plsqldev.log

Learn more about internal errors (for developers):
http://www.eurekalog.com/help/eurekalog/internal_errors.php
```

Please help to fix the second problem.